# How to point to several questions when flagging as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

My question was flagged as duplicate (or actually, administratively set as duplicate) and two questions were pointed to as the source to go to (rightly, both indeed apply):

[image]

How to mark several questions as the ones to go to? When I try to flag for duplicates, I either get a list of suggestions, or can input mine -- but just one.

Comment: Multiple users suggested different targets, or a gold badge owner edited the list.

Comment: Unless you have a gold badge (or you're a mod), you can't do this yourself. In the occasions I do find a question that is a dupe of multiple others, my go-to method is to close-vote with the main dupe then commend with the other(s). Just avoid saying the word "duplicate" in your comment, though - when a question *is* closed as a dupe due to voting, the system will "helpfully" remove any comments that say "duplicate". The idea is to remove the automatically generated comments "Possible duplicate of" but it also drops comments that point to a different question.

Comment: we (gold badge owner) have a magic *edit* link to update that list like we want ... you can see this in the timeline: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58450687/timeline ... as a side note: you can only close with one question and later edit to add more

Comment: I didn't even know I could edit the list--this is great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gold badge owners can edit the duplicates (both remove and add).

However one can just flag for one. If you want to help a gold badger doing his duty, Add another comment below the duplicate one:

> Possible duplicate of [a]
>
> also: [b] [c]

Then these can be edited in easily.